# Why is arima(1,0,2) output for non-stationary data in adf test?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, stationarity

According to adf test, the data set is non stationary but the best arima model is (1,0,2). However, non stationary data set must have d value differ from 0, right?
[image]

Comment: Apparently `auto.arima` does not use `adf.test` the way you do. You could read about `auto.arima` in its help file or some other place and find out what exactly the difference is.